# CSS responsive - Lines under logo

Tags: html, css, responsive

I have some trouble with lines going under/behind my logo on smaller screens/mobile devices. There need to be x% of space between the lines and the logo, but when the screen gets smaller the line goes behind the logo. (You can try to change the width of the fiddle preview.)

```css
header {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 225px;
  background-color: #000;
}
.logo {
  position: relative;
  top: -10px;
}
.line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 80px;
  text-align: center;
}
.line span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}
.line span:before,
.line span:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #FFF;
}
.line span:before {
  right: 60%;
  width: 80%;
  margin-right: 5%;
}
.line span:after {
  left: 60%;
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: 5%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="line">
    <span>
          <a href="#"><img class="logo" src="http://i.imgur.com/cPe20kT.png"></a>
        </span>
  </div>
</header>
```

View on [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6da97vrL/)

**Note**: The black background is just an example, the real background is NOT black.

Comment: some times the `x%` even cause some responsive issues.. i'll share you the alternative way of doing this :)

Comment: "x% of space between the lines and the logo".  x% of what space?  Is it a percentage of the logo width, the screen width, or the line width?  You're percentage value has to be "of something" to logically work and until that information is known, an adequate solution is difficult to provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `flexbox` and things become a lot easier:

1. Remove the `absolute` positioning of the `before` and `after`.
2. Use `display: flex` instead of `inline-block` for `.line span`

   ```
   .line span {
     display: flex;
     justify-content:center;
     margin: 0 5%;
   }
   ```

   `justity-content: center` added to center it horizontally.
3. Also added some margin to `a` and `.line span`- maybe you need to adjust it more?

```css
header {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 225px;
  background-color: #000;
}
.logo {
  position: relative;
  top: -10px;
}
.line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 80px;
  text-align: center;
}
.line span {
  display: flex;
  justify-content:center;
  margin: 0 5%;
}
a {
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.line span:before,
.line span:after {
  content: "";
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #FFF;
}
.line span:before {
  width: 80%;
  margin-right: 5%;
}
.line span:after {
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: 5%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="line">
    <span>
          <a href="#"><img class="logo" src="http://i.imgur.com/cPe20kT.png"></a>
        </span>
  </div>
</header>
```